# Databound controls and best practices

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

What is the current feeling about the use of databound controls?  When I first started using a RAD framework I remember many people on the message boards that I belonged to were very much against the use of databound controls.

IMO they greatly speed up development - but are they considered a good practice in the industry?

Answer (score 1):

I think databound controls are great!  I would also consider them to be a good practice considering the fact that Microsoft themselves use it extensively and continue to do so throughout the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

They are definitely considered a good practice by the industry.
Data-bound controls are elements of UI Data binding which is a software design pattern for simplifying development of GUI applications.

Answer (score 0):

It leads to good practises, see this link for elegant uses of databound controls: [techniques for implementing these common data access patterns in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/?lang=cs)
. You might actually find a lot more interesting stuff.